# Can't redeploy site using AWS SDK

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-sdk

I've got an IIS site published to a Win 2008 R2 server which has some other things installed on it (eg mail server).

Every time I've had a change to publish, I've simply used the AWS SDK's `Republish to stack 'X'` option and it's packaged the site, uploaded it, restarted the webserver and resumed without problem.

However, now when I go to the republish option, it doesn't give me an option to continue...

[image]

As you can see, the Next and Deploy buttons are disabled. They often take a second or two to enable (presumably while AWS is queried for some status).

If I go the long way 'round through Publish->Redeploy, I get the following

[image]

The site is up and responding, I can RDP into the server and everything seems okay.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We are having this problem now and I have seen it in the past.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I never found a _good_ answer. It seems that although the VM was still running (serving pages and OS responsive), the AWS management layer was failing to interact with it properly. Eg I could request a shutdown/terminate through the console but it never completed. In the end, I did an AWS terminate (so it was expecting a machine shutdown), logged into the box and did a shutdown. I then deployed to a new VM stack and have been using the new one ever since. FWIW I keep non-website services on a different VM now.

Comment: Got this resolved today by rebooting both servers in that group.  Probably just needed to restart the AWS service running on the machines.  This would be a bigger deal if we had say 10-20 servers in that group...